# How to edit a class instance through a WTForm

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to set up a settings page, where the currently logged in user would be able to adjust a few (currently two) attributes of the user class.  I am using SQLAlchemy to handle my database queries.  The settings page and form displays and works before I attempt to tie in the user class, so I believe it's an issue with my Flask code. I attempted to follow the example code in the [WTForms crash course documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/crash_course.html), but that still resulted in an error.   Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Flask Code:

```
class SettingsForm(Form):
    topics = TextField('Topics')
    emailFrequency= RadioField('Email Frequency', choices = [('Daily', u'Daily'), ('Weekly', u'Weekly'), ('Monthly', u'Monthly'), ('Never', u'Never')], default='Weekly')
    submit = SubmitField("Save Changes")

@application.route('/settings', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def settings(request):
    user = current_user
    form = SettingsForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        user.emailFrequency = form.emailFrequency.data 
        user.topics = form.topics.data
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('settings.html', page_title = "Success", form=form, success=True)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('settings.html', page_title = 'Customize your settings using the form below', form = form)
```

HTML

```
{% extends "base-layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% if success %}
        <h2> Settings updated! </h2>
    {% else %}
        <h2> Customize your settings</h2>
         <form class="form" action="{{url_for('settings')}}" method="POST" role="form">
            {{form.hidden_tag()}}
            <div> {{form.topics.label}} </div>
            <div> {{form.topics(placeholder="E.g. Gas, Oil, Renewables", class="form-control")}} </div>
            <div> {{form.emailFrequency.label}} </div>
            <div> {{form.emailFrequency}} </div>
            <div> {{form.submit}} </div>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps if anyone else has the same issue, the form worked when I removed the request input to the settings function as follows:

```
@application.route('/settings', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def settings():
    user = current_user
    form = SettingsForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        user.emailFrequency = form.emailFrequency.data 
        user.topics = form.topics.data
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('settings.html', page_title = "Success", form=form, success=True)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('settings.html', page_title = 'Customize your settings using the form below', form = form)
```

If anyone would like to explain why that worked, that would be helpful in the future.